# Laravel blade soft-migrating to Vue.js - how to handle tags?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a Laravel application using blade templates. I want to start learning and migrating the tamplates to Vue, but one part at a time, so I would use both Blade and Vue.js on my code for some time, until I fully migrate to vue.

My problem is, they have similar tags {{ varname }} is exactly the same on both Blade and Vue.

I'm a beginner to Vue.js. My question is, how to approach this? How could I use both at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can escape `{{ }}` in Blade by prefixing `@`.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#blade-and-javascript-frameworks

```
@{{ varname }}
```